# WebRatio: Unable to locate companion shared library

Tags: model-view-controller, launcher

I'm having this issue on Mac, WebRatio.app is showing this error after extracting the package.

> The WebRatio executable launcher was unable to locate its companion
>   shared library

I haven't changed any file location or renamed any folder, I have installed Java SE Runtime Environment as well.

Am I missing anything Important?

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal, you should run the following command to remove these extended attributes:

```
xattr -c WebRatio.app
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way i've found by 'showing package contents' of WebRatio.app and accessing WebRatio.exec

> Contents>MacOS>WebRatio.exec

Answer (score 0):

as reported on the official WebRatio forum (https://www.webratio.com/forum/question-details/web-ratio-mobile-plateform-macos-sierra) if you are running WebRatio on Mac OS Sierra you can follow these steps:

- Select the WebRatio file stored into WebRatio.app/Contents/MacOS
- Open the context menu (right click of mouse) and select Make Alias item
- Move the alias in the "root" folder (at the same level of the WebRatio.app file)
- Double click on the alias in order to run WebRatio.